# How to manage snackbar wrapper state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to create a simple wrapper for `v-snackbar` but there is a problem that I cannot use a prop value as argument in`v-model`. I am trying to pass a boolean as a prop to the wrapper and to change the inner state but the problem is that it works only once because the code to open the snackbar sets the ref to `true` and the watch function does not recognize that as a change. What is the proper way to create a wrapper for a snackbar in vue?

```
        <v-btn @click="showSnackbar = true">
            Open Snackbar
        </v-btn>
        <Snackbar :options="{ showSnackbar: showSnackbar }"> Warning </Snackbar>
```

wrapper code:

```
<template>
    <v-snackbar v-model="isShowing">
        <slot></slot>
        <template #actions>
            <v-btn variant="text" @click="isShowing = false">
                Close
            </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
    options: SnackbarOptions
}>(), {

})
const isShowing = ref(false);
watch(() => props.options.showSnackbar, () => {
    isShowing.value = true
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the snackbar is opened the first time `showSnackbar` in your parent component is never set back to false. If it's never set back to false, then it can never be "watched" as being set to true again. Since there's no two-way binding between the components this is expected.

You could easily just use v-model with the `showSnackbar` property, or if you want to *only* do this using the `options` prop and no v-model, you can use a computed property instead of a watcher, but you'll still need to at least add an event listener:

**Parent**

```html
<Snackbar
  :options="{ showSnackbar: showSnackbar }"
  @close="showSnackbar = false"
>
  Warning
</Snackbar>
```

**Wrapper**

```js
<script setup>
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  const props = defineProps(['options'])
  const emit = defineEmits(['close'])

  const showSnackbar = computed({
    get() {
      return props.options.showSnackbar
    },
    set() {
      emit('close')
    },
  })
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="showSnackbar">
    <slot></slot>
    <template #actions>
      <v-btn variant="text" @click="showSnackbar = false"> Close </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>
```

[demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

#### Solution with v-model

**Parent**

```html
<Snackbar v-model="showSnackbar" :options="otherOptions"> Warning </Snackbar>
```

**Wrapper**

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['options'])
const showSnackbar = defineModel()
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="showSnackbar">
    <slot></slot>
    <template #actions>
      <v-btn variant="text" @click="showSnackbar = false"> Close </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! What do you mean by `easily just use v-model`? I am kind of new to Vue and I dont really understand how to do it with `v-model`. If it easier I will happily switch to it

Comment: I've updated the answer showing how to use `v-model` in the parent and `defineModel` in the wrapper component.  It creates a two-way binding so updating `showSnackbar` in either component immediately updates it in the other.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpful. Now I know how to pass a `v-model` value deep!